# Haskell - using Until on a list

Tags: haskell

I've been trying to do a function that creates a list of n numbers ([1...n]) using an until. So far I haven't found any examples of until manipulating lists and I've been improvising:

```
sequence Int -> [Int]
sequence x = until (== x) (++ [ +1 ]) [1]
```

But keep getting the Syntax error in expression (unexpected token) error

I know I could simply use a [1..n] to create the list, but I really want to make this work out. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The problems are that 1) you need a `::` between `sequence` and `Int -> Int`, 2) the `+1` as you wrote it doesn't mean anything, and 3) building a list directly with `until` this way won't ever be efficient, you need to carry a state with it.

Comment: Why do you want to use until for this? It does not look as a good candidate for the task. Is the goal itself to learn how to use until?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take note of the type of `until`:

```
until :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

For your case, `a` is `[Int]`, so everything has to take a list as input and return a list.

```
sequence x = until (\y -> last y == x) (\y -> y ++ [last y + 1]) [1]
```

- The predicate takes a list and checks if its last element is equal to `x`.
- The modifier takes a list and adds a new element to the end, with that new element being one greater than the last element of the list.

This is not very efficient, as you are continually working with the wrong end of the list. You can make it a little more efficient by building the list backwards, then reversing it at the end. (Since we are guaranteed to be using non-empty lists, I use `head` in place of pattern matching for simplicity.)

```
sequence x = reverse $ until ((== x) . head) (\y -> (head y + 1) : y) [1]
```

or build the list down from `x` to 1:

```
sequence x = until ((==1) . head) (\y -> head y-1 : y) [x]
```

Comment: The second version is more than 'a little' more efficient - it is asymptotically faster than the first.

Comment: When I wrote that, I think I was already comparing it to `sequence x = seq 1 where seq y = y : if y == x then [] else seq (y + 1)` in my mind.